# onClick attribute for JSX react element not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The onClick attribute for a button element created within a variable is not firing.

I tried directly defining the function in the onClick attribute, and simply out-putting to the console, but there is still nothing output to the console, and the button is not working as expected.

I also added a 'disabled={false}' attribute to the button to make sure that was not an issue, but the onClick attribute is still not working as expected.

```
let display = (<div className ='dtaskhome'>
    <h1>Tasks</h1>
    <button disabled={false} onClick={newTask} className='btask'>New Task +</button>
    <ul className ='ultasks'>{taskItems}</ul>
</div>);

function newTask() {
   console.log('point reached');
    Tasks.props.state.newTask = true;
}
```

No error messages related to the onClick attribute are being displayed, and the current code correctly renders the component.

Comment: ``newTask = () => {
   console.log('point reached');
    Tasks.props.state.newTask = true;
}``

Comment: In web programming, the word **responsive** does not mean it doesn't work or it doesn't gives you the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

> I also added a 'disabled={false}' attribute to the button to make sure
>   that was not an issue, but the onClick attribute is still not
>   responsive.

Try implementing the function as a method.

```
newTaskHandler = (props) => {
   console.log('point reached');
   props.state.newTask = true;
}
```

Then try

```
onClick={this.newTask(this.props)}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

try to call the function:

```
onClick={newTask()}
```

And if not try to call it with this.

```
onClick={this.newTask()}
```

Comment: The issue with this solution is that it causes the new component to render, regardless of whether or not the button was clicked.